# How to pass vector object to a virtual function?

Tags: c++, function, class, vector, virtual

Can anybody tell me how can I pass vector to virtual function? When I try to compile I get some errors like 'Car' : undeclared identifier and 'Car' cannot instantiate abstract class? Anyone guess what I did wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Handling
{
public:
    virtual void add_car() = 0;
    virtual void erase_car() = 0;
    virtual void show_car(vector<Car> _carvector) = 0;
};


class Car : virtual public Handling
{
public:
    string manufacturer;
    string model;
    string type;
    int engine;
    string enginetype;
    int yearofproduction;
    string geartype;
    int noofgears;
    string price;

    _manufacturer = "Opel";
_model = "Astra";
_type = "Hatchback";
_engine = 1900;
_enginetype = "Diesel";
_yearofproduction = 1999;
_geartype = "Manual";
_noofgears = 5;
_price = "5600";

    Car(){};
    Car(string _manufacturer, string _model, string _type, int _enigne, string _enginetype, int _yearofproduction, string _geartype, int _noofgears, string _price);

    void add_car()
    {

    }

    void erase_car()
    {

    }

    void show_car(vector<Car> _carvector)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _carvector.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "Samochod nr. " << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Marka: " << _carvector[i].manufacturer << endl;
            cout << "Model: " << _carvector[i].model << endl;
            cout << "Typ: " << _carvector[i].type << endl;
            cout << "Pojemnosc silnika: " << _carvector[i].engine << " cm3" << endl;
            cout << "Rodzaj silnika: " << _carvector[i].enginetype << endl;
            cout << "Rok produkcji: " << _carvector[i].yearofproduction << endl;
            cout << "Rodzaj skrzyni biegow: " << _carvector[i].geartype << endl;
            cout << "Liczba biegow: " << _carvector[i].noofgears << endl;
            cout << "Cena: " << _carvector[i].price << " PLN" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

Car::Car(string _manufacturer, string _model, string _type, int _engine, string _enginetype, int _yearofproduction, string _geartype, int _noofgears, string _price)
    : manufacturer(_manufacturer)
    , model(_model)
    , type(_type)
    , engine(_engine)
    , enginetype(_enginetype)
    , yearofproduction(_yearofproduction)
    , geartype(_geartype)
    , noofgears(_noofgears)
    , price(_price)
{
}

int main()
{
vector<Car> carvector;

Car carobject;

    string _manufacturer;
    string _model;
    string _type;
    int _engine;
    string _enginetype;
    int _yearofproduction;
    string _geartype;
    int _noofgears;
    string _price

carvector.push_back(Car(_manufacturer, _model, _type, _engine, _enginetype,_yearofproduction, _geartype, _noofgears, _price));
carobject.show_car(carvector);
```

Comment: The second error is probably caused by the first error.

Comment: 1. Predeclare car. 2. Make show_car in `class Car` virtual. 3. Having a parent class depend on a child class like that breaks the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) so throw out this design and try again.

Comment: Also, get rid of this before it becomes a habit: `using namespace std` - instead do `std::vector<Car>`

Comment: You have a base interface `Handling` that refers to a derived type `Car`. That usually points to a broken design, and even if you can fix the compiler errors you'll run into higher-level problems trying to *use* these classes appropriately.

Comment: Also, all of this business: `_manufacturer = "Opel";` and `_model = "Astra";` is not a thing.  Your variables don't have `_` in front of them and you certainly can't assign to them in the class body like that.  Are you coming from Objective-C (not that this would even be correct in Objective-C)?

Comment: @IdeaHat _"1. Predeclare car."_ Forward celaration won't work in this case.

Comment: The `showCar` function probably should take the vector by const reference rather than by value in order to avoid copying the contents of the vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True, I should also have added "Change `std::vector<Car>` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Car>>`"

Comment: I need to have pure virtual class (in this case is Handling class). So how can other class inherit form class Handling?

Comment: Anyway, I don't see a point to have this `Handling` class as an abstract base. The design (or the sample) is pretty poor. _"I need to have pure virtual class"_ Why really? Any other piece of code needs to know `Car` and `Handling` anyway. So I don't see a point for `Handling`.

Comment: It's an academic excercise -.-

Comment: @wisniowy _"It's an academic excercise"_ Well, abstract inheritance in the way you show here doesn't make sense though. We can't really fix this for you I'm afraid.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I thought the same... but it seems it's working on recent gcc

Comment: @TomaszKłak Uhm what?!?

Comment: @wisniowy - `class Car : virtual public Handling`  So a `Car` is-a `Handling`?  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ forward declaration of Car

Comment: @TomaszKłak Forward declaration needs to use a pointer or smart pointer in the `std::vector` then anyway.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I know that the size of type needs to be known there but still... its working

Comment: @TomaszKłak Mind to show me a [fixed version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003a74d474219810) of what you mean?

Comment: but still I got error and it's not my idea to make this class virtual, but my teacher cannot understand some facts and so far i have to that

Comment: Is it possible you're reading your assignment wrong?  I find it hard to believe a C++ teacher designed or wrote any of the code you've shown.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ https://gist.github.com/tumdum/f4ebf2b765c340025f16 and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1208f5a2ea35a883

Comment: @TomaszKłak Hmmm, interesting. I learn something new about c++ everyday. You may post this as an answer. But anyway the design is hopelessly flawed. (BTW use just coliru, it's much easier than hassling with github gists).

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I agree about the design and I'm not going to post something which I don't even understand. More likely I will post this as question tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That little line of code put before declaration of Handling class did the thing.

```
class Car;
```